# Can't resolve symbol error while creating title

Tags: java, android, xml, string

Iam getting an error in my `main.xml` file while creating title.I have added the title in my `string.xml` file.
here is my `main.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
     />
</menu>
```

and my `string.xml` file

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Github Query</string>
    <!--TODO (1) Add a string resource called search with the title "Search"-->
        <String name="search">Search</String>
    </resources>
```

Iam newbie

Comment: Make sure main.xml is it in Menu folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `'s'tring` instead of `'S'tring` (Case Sensitive)

```
<string name="search">Search</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've made a copy paste error in your question, but you have a capital "S" in string in your XML. Should be,

```
<string name="search">Search</string>
```